# C# Read/Load multiple images for one row of info

Tags: c#, mysql, database

The App should show multiple rows of info. Each row has some basic ***string*** infos, with serveral ***reference images***. In MySQL database, I have **table A** storing basic infos, **table B** with all image paths. Problem is, now even though there's only 1 row, the Reader reads 3 times and creates 3 UserControl slides, which is not what I want. The simplified code below:

```
string sql = "SELECT a.id, a.name, b.imgPath FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

While(reader.Read())
{
UserControl userControl= new UserControl();
userControl.idLabel = reader.GetInt32("id").Tostring();
userControl.nameLabel = reader.GetString("name");
string imgPath = reader.GetString("imgPath");
Image img = New Image(...);
stackPanel.Children.Add(userControl);
}
```

How to solve this? Thanks a lot !

Comment: How do you add the image to the userControl?

Comment: Referring to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), it look like the way you're handling the MySQLDataReader is fine. Are you sure your MySQL query is only returning one row? When you step through in debug, what are the results? When you say "simplified code", what are you omitting?

Comment: Do u want the first image?   Image count perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not returning one row, `join` will return a row per joined pair, so you will get as many rows as pictures it has. The solution for this is to check if you already have added a control for the same row, in that case retrieve it and add the new image to the control, else create the new control as you have done.

```
While(reader.Read())
{

    string id = reader.GetInt32("id").ToString();
    //Check if there is already a userControl for the current item id
    UserControl userControl= stackPanel.Children.OfType<UserControl>().Where(uc => uc.idLabel == id).FirstOrDefault();

    i( userControl == null)
    {
        userControl = new UserControl();
        userControl.idLabel = id.Tostring();
        userControl.nameLabel = reader.GetString("name");
        stackPanel.Children.Add(userControl);
    }
    string imgPath = reader.GetString("imgPath");
    Image img = New Image(...);
    //Add the new image to your control. You haven't show how you add images to it.
}
```

Comment: Hi Gusman, thanks for your guid. One question is, when I use Linq method "Where", VS doesn't recognize the mothod hence without any auto-generated code, even though I have included System.Linq to my Class. Do you  know why?

Comment: @JesseGao Sorry, you meant the `stackPanel.Children.Where`, right? I missed the type cast, else Linq can't iterate it. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Now it actually comes to the part of adding multiple images to each UserControl, which I haven't figured out how to yet.The UserControl is dynamically generated by each database row, and each iamge is also a independent row. Is there a existing solution for this kind of scenario? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @JesseGao Glad it worked, remember to accept the answer if it was correct. About the usercontrol, no, there is no imagegallery, caroussel or similar view. A simple way to do it would be to add a FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel (depends on your UI dessign) as main container and each time a new image is added you create a picturebox, set it's Image and add it to the panel.